# How do I skip all tests in a subtest if windows?

Tags: windows, perl, testing

I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work

```
subtest 'catalyst scripts that should be executable' => sub {
    plan({ skip_all => 'skip failing executable tests on windows' }) if $^O eq 'MSWin32';
    my $should_exec =  [ @{ $dzpcs->scripts } ];

    foreach ( @{ $should_exec } ) {
        ok  ( -x $_ , "$_" . ' is executable' );
    }
};
```

Here's what I got in my cpants report.

> plan() doesn't understand HASH(0x286f4cc) at t/02-MintingProfileCatalyst.t line 46.
>     # Child (catalyst scripts that should be executable) exited without calling finalize()
>
> #   Failed test 'catalyst scripts that should be executable'
> #   at C:/strawberry/perl/lib/Test/Builder.pm line 252.
> # Tests were run but no plan was declared and done_testing() was not seen.

So I guess it's not a hash, not really sure what it is then... what's the cleanest way to make this work? *(p.s. I can't test win32, I only have my Linux box)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`plan` takes two parameters, not a hashref:

```
plan( skip_all => 'skip failing executable tests on windows' ) if $^O eq 'MSWin32';
```

Not everything uses [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose). ;-)

Note: for testing purposes, you could change `eq` to `ne`, so it will skip the tests on your Linux box.  Just remember to change it back afterwards.

Comment: why is it `=>` instead of `,` most of the time `=>` signifies a hash key.

Comment: `=>` also called the **fat-comma operator** can be substituted with a `,`. The only difference is that `=>` quotes the bareword preceding it. Example: `plan( 'skip_all', 'skip message' ) ...`

Comment: `=>` is also frequently used for named parameters.  It's just a style choice.  Otherwise, you'd have to put quotes around `skip_all`.  But you can use a regular comma if you prefer.  The point is you have to pass `plan` two strings, not a hashref with one key.

Comment: I just tried this, and plan( skip_all => '...' ) appears to stop the entire test script, not just the current subtest.